# React Build with Jenkins - ERROR: "build-js" exited with 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm currently migrating my local Jenkins to a new EC2 instance and in transferring the UI build pipeline, I currently am getting the following error during build:

`ERROR: "build-js" exited with 1.`

I had received this previously on the current Jenkins server, however, it was resolved by doing the following:

`react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=4096 build`

Server / build details:

```
t3.large - 2 vCPU and 8gb Ram
Amazon Linux - 64bit x86
Node 16.14.0
```

I have tried multiple options with the build, however, none of them appear to want to work. The max-old-space doesn't even seem to be doing anything. Not even sure what other options are available.

Answer (score 2):

Try to build your react app with CI flag set to false

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "CI=false && react-scripts build",
  }
```

If this doesnt work then try directly change the flag

```
CI=false react-scripts run build
```

*react-scripts needs to be replaced depending on wht you use

Comment: I've done this as well to no avail.

Comment: @smb I will dig into this later more, thats indeed a weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `--max_old_space_size` indicate how much memory your build process can use, try make it bigger:
`react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8192 build`

Comment: I've done this, however the Large instance the Jenkins server is on has a maximum of 8gb and setting to 8192 didn't fix it. I have another local server with jenkins and its set and runs just fine, however, on AWS it does not.